# How do I hide an 'unshared' directory?

Tags: networking, nfs

I'm sharing a directory with another user. This directory is called `/home/Shared`.

When I was setting up the home network ([that's another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87422/nfs-setup-access-denied)), I found the 'Shared' directory with read access in the "Browse Network" part of Nautilus.

I'm not aware of having shared this directory on the network, it doesn't show up in `/etc/fstab`, nor in `/mnt` on the Server.

How can I remove this directory? 
As a side note, I'm not seeing my own home directory in the share.

Comment: You have to provide more information. What have you done? What technologies do you use? It's not immediately clear to me what an SO-User is.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't using the shared directory in YOUR home?  i.e. /home/yourname/shared?  Because that is obviously intended to be shared, so don't put things in there you don't want to share.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad, SO = Significant Other (in this case, the wife :-) I'm with Ubuntu 11.10. I'm trying to set up an NFS network. I did achieve an FTP server. And, no, I didn't put any link or directory in my shared file.

Comment: @jrg. The problem is that I still see this dir being mounted, but I have no idea how I shared it. How can someone obtain the information about the shared directories. There should be a file somewhere /etc/host??? where this behavior is defined. I think that's a valid question even though the problem is very localized. :-)

Comment: @GUIJunkie Sorry, I voted to close this as abandoned as part of our cleanup - this question appeared to be abandoned, and you have stated that it isn't. :) I have cast a vote to reopen, as well as notified a moderator of this. Thanks for leaving a comment!

Comment: @jrg, thanks for the edit and for reopening the question.

Comment: I checked all the files from the NFSHowTo, no reference to the 'shared' folder. Also sudo nautilus doesn't show the folder as a shared one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look **Shares** and **Automounter** parts here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

It seems the folder `/home/Shared` can be *Samba* or even *Apple* software related.

Can be helpful:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1902093

```
testparm -s
```

look in your `/usr/local/etc/smb.conf` some about (part of out from link above):

```
[shared]
comment = Shared Folder
path = /home/shared
valid users = +samba, +dakids
read list = +dakids
write list = +samba
read only = No
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
browseable = No
```

Comment: It might be autofs, I'll look into it. This system is 100% Ubuntu, so it might be Samba even though it's not installed directly, but Apple?

Comment: hm...look another workaround:
http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1163489

Comment: iTunes perhaps is using this dir

Comment: Solved! testparam -s showed my Samba config at /etc/samba/smb.conf
 with the shared folder. Cheers.